# Laravel: Filter threads by clickable categories

Tags: laravel, categories, forum

I made a page with a categories list on the left and threads on the right side. List of categories are dynamically displayed with CRUD in different controller as threads. And all that works.

ForumThread controller index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $threads = ForumThread::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    $categories = ForumCategory::with('threads')->get();

    return view('forum.thread.index', compact('threads', 'categories'));
}
```

threads belongs to categories of course and view with categories part look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <a href="{{route('forum.index')}}" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">{{$threads->count()}}</span>
      All categories
    </a>

    @foreach ($categories as $category)

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">{{$category->threads->count()}}</span>
      {{$category->name}}
    </a>

    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

The thing I want is to set a href link to go to threads that belongs to that specific category that is clicked.

I presume that I need a new method for this (I presume because I don't know how to make this happened in index method) so I made one:

```
public function showThreads($id)
{
    $showThreads = ForumCategory::with('threads')->findOrFail($id);

    return view('forum.thread.index', compact('showThreads'));
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('/forum/category/{id}', 'ForumThreadController@showThreads')->name('category.threads');
```

and when I set id for example '/forum/category/3' and try function dd(showThreads->thread); it shows me an array of threads which belongs to that category id.

But now I don't know how to implement this in this foreach loop that already working for category list. I tried like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <a href="{{route('forum.index')}}" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">{{$threads->count()}}</span>
      All categories
    </a>

    @foreach ($categories as $category)

    <a href="{{ route('category.threads', $showThreads->id) }}" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">{{$category->threads->count()}}</span>
      {{$category->name}}
    </a>

    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

but it shows me error: **Undefined variable: threads**

Any help?

Comment: you are using `$threads` but you didn't pass that variable to the view.

Comment: I did passthat variable but in index method. The error appear because I use one more method in same view, that's the problem...